# Conflict between mathdesign and Heuristica

Tags: fonts, pdftex, incompatibility, mathdesign

When using the packages `mathdesign` and [`heuristica`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/heuristica) together, small caps don't render properly. Like so:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[osf,scaled=.92]{heuristica}

\begin{document}
  \textsc{qwertyuiop}
\end{document}
```

The output shows lower case letters instead of small caps. Other packages like `fourier` don't have the same problem, but I would still prefer to use `mathdesign`. I like the math font better.

Is there a way to fix the conflict, or to grab only the math fonts from `mathdesign`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write into the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\textsc[1]{{\fontfamily{put}\fontshape{sc}\selectfont#1}}
```

or use the font setting as provided in the documentation of Heuristica:

```
\usepackage[osf,scaled=.92]{heuristica}
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata} % typewriter
\usepackage[type1,scaled=.95]{cabin} % sans serif like Gill Sans
\usepackage[utopia,vvarbb,bigdelims]{newtxmath}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I needed with a small modification: `\renewcommand*{\scshape}{\fontfamily{Heuristica-TOsF}\fontshape{sc}\selectfont}` . I tried `newtxmath` also but for some reason it rendered functions like `\log` or `\sin` in Computer Modern. It could be my fault since I updated it manually; I'll find out in about a month when TeX Live thaws.